# Convolutional Neural Network visualization - weights or activations?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, data-visualization, conv-neural-network

[image]

Is the above visualization a rendering of the *weights* of the first convolutional layer or the *activations* on a given input image on the first convolutional layer?

Below is a visualization of the weights of the first convolutional layer of the Inception v2 model that I've been training for 48 hours:

[image: Inception]

I'm sure I have not converged my model after only 48 hours (on a CPU). Shouldn't those weights begin to smooth out by now, where training accuracy is over 90%?

Comment: FYI - I asked about this question [on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371811/are-questions-about-visualizations-of-neural-networks-on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [ImageNet Classification with Deep Convolutional Neural Networks](https://www.nvidia.cn/content/tesla/pdf/machine-learning/imagenet-classification-with-deep-convolutional-nn.pdf), The first convolutional layer takes as input a 224x224x3 image (note: should be 227x227 instead of 224x224) and filters it with 96 kernels of size 11x11x3.

The figure above shows the convolutional kernels learned by the first convolutional layer.

note: in fact in the figure is possible count 96 convolutional kernels that sould be of size 11×11×3.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular The weight of the first layer of an AlexNet is being visualized. In terms of Activation visualization the visuals are not as smooth as visuals of weights.

Let me know if you have questions

Comment: I added to my question. At what point do you think my weights would begin to smooth out? I've been training on a 150K sample training set for about 5 epochs (batch size of 16).

Comment: Im not able to make sense of the weights that you have posted , Usually irrespective of the network, the initial weights learn image edges, blobs , low level things etc,

Comment: Right. What I'm trying to narrow down is if I just haven't trained my model enough or if I'm way off target altogether. I've read that Inception v2 "learns" the ImageNet dataset in about a week on a GPU. Since I'm only training on a single CPU, I'm guessing the same process might take me a week, but I'm trying to gauge my progress in part by checking the weights/filters to see if they smooth out.

Comment: Not sure if that's the road you want to take if as you say you want know if you have trained your model enough, plot your training and more importantly your val curve, that should give you a better idea.