# Visualizing Neural Network Layer Activation

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

Feature visualizing in tensor flow or keras is easy and can be found here. https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-visualize-filters-and-feature-maps-in-convolutional-neural-networks/ or [Convolutional Neural Network visualization - weights or activations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51616888/convolutional-neural-network-visualization-weights-or-activations)

how to do this in pytorch?

I am using PyTorch with pretrained resnet18 model. All i need to input the image and get activation for specific layer(e.g. Layer2.0.conv2). Layer2.0.conv2 is specified in the pretrained model.

In simple words; how to convert link one code to PyTorch? how to get the specific layers in resnet18 PyTorch and how to get the activation for input image.
I tried this in tensorflow and it worked but not PyTorch.

Comment: You can directly access layer weight tensors, ex `Layer2.conv2.weights`. You can almost directly copy the code in the first link you posted and just replace the appropriate `torch` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would have to register PyTorch's hooks on specific layer. See [this tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/former_torchies/nnft_tutorial.html#forward-and-backward-function-hooks) for intro about hooks.

Basically, it allows to capture `input/output` of `forward/backward` going into the `torch.nn.Module`. Whole thing could be a bit complicated, there exists a library with similar goal to your (disclaimer I'm the author), called [`torchfunc`](https://szymonmaszke.github.io/torchfunc/#torchfunc). Especially [`torchfunc.hooks.recorder`](https://szymonmaszke.github.io/torchfunc/packages/torchfunc.hooks/torchfunc.hooks.recorders.html) allows you to do what you want, see code snippet and comments below:

```
import torchvision
import torchfunc

my_network = torchvision.resnet18(pretrained=True)
# Recorder saving inputs to all submodules
recorder = torchfunc.hooks.recorders.ForwardPre()

# Will register hook for all submodules of resnet18
# You could specify some submodules by index or by layer type, see docs
recorder.modules(my_networks)

# Push example image through network
my_network(torch.randn(1, 3, 224, 224))
```

You could `register` recorder only for some layers (submodule) specified by `index` or layer type, to get necessary info, run:

```
# Zero image before going into the third submodule of this network
recorder.data[3][0]

# You can see all submodules and their positions by running this:    
for i, submodule in enumerate(my_network.modules()):
    print(i, submodule)

# Or you can just print the network to get this info
print(my_network)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. it's really helpful. you just save my day.

Comment: recorder = torchfunc.hooks.recorders.ForwardPre()

Comment: one more issue. once the recorder is called and we input some data(image) to network and plot the recorder. if i want to perform this operation multiple time. should i set different recoders?

Comment: What do you mean by multiple times? Each image passed through network will be recorded if the recorder got registered. Multiple recorders would be useful if you save data based on some `condition` which is not the case here I suppose. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. multiple pass means that more than one image is pass through the network. i observed that it record it but the dimension of each tensor doesn't make any senses. i think it only capture the input tensor.   
1) i register the recorder 
2) pass two images to the network
3) check the recorder but it only caputure the input tensors
4) e.g Conv1 in resnet18, it's output is only 3 channels but the network output has 64. how to capture the output of each conv not the input.

Comment: There are multiple recorders available. To record outputs of layer, use `torchfunc.hooks.recorders.ForwardOutput`, `torchfunc.hooks.recorders.ForwardInput` would record inputs to the layers. Experiment with them to get a better understanding of what they are after, but those are largely modeled after PyTorch's hooks and naming convention follows. I would also advise you to experiment with `modules` methods and recording based on types and/or index of layers. Just remember, weightless modules are in the network __only once__, e.g. `ReLU` and it may be problematic. sometimes.

Comment: Does this library also support 1d?